# Edit XML files with python

Tags: python, xml, xslt, text-mining

I'm trying to edit several XML files at the same time using python.
In the original XML files I have Spekers and what they say but not as parent-child tag. Like this:

```
     <p Speaker>John</p>
     <p Text>Speech he's giving</p>
     <p Text>Speech he's giving</p>
     <p Speaker>Laura</p>
     <p Text>Speech she's giving</p>
     <p Text>Speech she's giving</p>
```

But I want to make a parent-child relation between speaker and text. Besides in a database that I already have with the information of the speakers, I would like to add their information like their speakerid, their role, and create a count of the times they speak. just like this:

```
    <u xml:id="speakercount.u1"
           who="#speakerid"
           ana="#role">
           <seg xml:id="speechcount.u1.1">text</seg>
           <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.1.2">text</seg>
       </u>
    <u xml:id="speakercount.u2"
           who="#speakerid"
           ana="#role">
           <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.2.1">text</seg>
           <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.2.2">text</seg>
    </u>
```

Is this possible to do? and to do it to several XML at once? What python modules I would need to do it? Because I can't seem to find the necessary information to do so...

Comment: You can solve this transformation with XSLT. I think you are mixing Text, data and logics in one go. Consider separating them. Use namespace declaration at the top of the XML. Use the namespace prefix in the elements and handle the needed counter as a separate logic mechanism, even if you would and should do the counter in the same tool. You should also clarify what you mean with "several XMl at once"? Several files, or transformation rounds?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! By several XML at once, I meant several files.

Comment: I think you can in XSLT 3.0 point out a folder with XML files that should be processed. But you would have to consult the XSLT specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xslt for this.

To give you some direction, i.e. build a singel xml file containing the db-info combined combined with the content of hose separate xml-files like this:

```
<root>
  <speakers>
    <speaker id="1" role="A" name="John"/>
    <speaker id="2" role="B" name="Laura"/>
  </speakers>
  <ps>
    <p type="Speaker">John</p>
    <p type="Text">Speech he's giving</p>
    <p type="Text">Speech he's giving</p>
    <p type="Speaker">Laura</p>
    <p type="Text">Speech she's giving</p>
    <p type="Text">Speech she's giving</p>    
  </ps>
</root>
```

And then use a xslt like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="speakers" as="element()*" select="/*/speakers/speaker"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[p]">
    <us>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[@type='Speaker']">
        <xsl:variable name="speakerName" select="current-group()[1]/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="speakerDbRecord" select="$speakers[@name=$speakerName]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="posSpeaker" select="position()"/>
        <u xml:id="speakercount.u{$posSpeaker}"
          who="#{$speakerDbRecord/@id}"
          ana="#{$speakerDbRecord/@role}">
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[ position() gt 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="posText" select="position() - 1"/>
            <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.{$posSpeaker}.{$posText}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></seg>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </u>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </us>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will give you this:

```
<us>
   <u xml:id="speakercount.u1" who="#1" ana="#A">
      <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.1.0">Speech he's giving</seg>
      <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.1.1">Speech he's giving</seg>
   </u>
   <u xml:id="speakercount.u2" who="#2" ana="#B">
      <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.2.0">Speech she's giving</seg>
      <seg xml:id="speechcount.u.2.1">Speech she's giving</seg>
   </u>
</us>
```